# Blank Activity não aparece no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Ao criar um novo projeto no `Android Studio` o escolhe o tipo de `activity`, como colocar o `Blank Activity` no `Android Studio`?

Comment: Olá, qual a versão do Android Studio que você está utilizando?

Comment: Se for aquela que ja aparece com o layout e o java agora se chama Basic Activity.

Comment: @CarlosBridi a versão 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependendo a versão que você está utilizando do Android Studio, pode ter ocorrido apenas um "rename" da activity Blank Activity. Na versão 2.1.2 tem a opção Empty Activity, que deve ser equivalente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: deve ser isso então